# Custom tableview with different cell

Tags: ios, tableview, custom-cell

I am new to iOS. I have a table view where i want to load different custom cells.

Here is my code from `tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (self.mainTableView .tag==SEARCH)
    {
        static NSString *cellId=@"Cella";
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            NSArray *topLevelOjects= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell=[topLevelOjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    //code goes here
    return cell;
}
else
{
    static NSString *mCell = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:mCell];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
    }
    //code goes here
    return cell;
}
```

In method n`umberOfRowsInSections:(UITableView *) tableview` I have:

```
    if (tableView.tag==SEARCH)
    {
        return [firstList count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [secondList count];
    }
```

The problem i have is that every time ELSE is executed the tableview contains both the first and second CustomCell. WHY?

Comment: Where is this code implemented? In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? What are you returning in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: I suggest to change `if(self.mainTableView.tag==SEARCH)` to `if(tableView.tag == SEARCH)`. Then when do you put the tag?

Comment: Also you will have to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` if the cell have different heights, otherwise  they will overlap.

Comment: The cells do have different size

Comment: what do u mean by tableview tag checking in if condition? why is that? do u have two tables?

Comment: I am using the same table but with different customcells.

Comment: where are u changing the tableview tag?

Comment: In viewDidLoad and in another methods I have:)

Comment: @justME try giving a break point on the if block and check if you get newcells allocated when else part is executed.. or it is using older cells dequed?

Comment: is it using older cells. Though in else the cell is of type UITableCell, in debuging mode the cell is of type CustomCell. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. The identifier used on else branch was actually the identifier used for the CustomCell *cell =.. (if branch). There was no Cella identifier:).